# android 360 camera app

Tags: android, camera, 360-degrees

I have been tasked with making an app which places an image in the world around the device and the user has to use the camera to look around and find the image/object. It should give off a sound as the user looks in the correct direction, to aid them in finding it.

I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction with how to go about something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you will need some knowledge in [OpenGl ES Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). If you don't have any then I suggest you follow this [Android OpenGl ES course](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html). It'll give you the basics on how to create an Object in a 3D world.

To get the camera preview as a background of the 3D world I suggest you [Vuforia](http://developer.vuforia.com/library/getting-started) library (go to the **Getting Started with Eclipse (Java/C++) on Android** section). This library is intended for Augmented Reality but it will help you get the camera preview as a background simply (it really is a pain in the ass to do it).

Basically you will :

- create a [GLSurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) in which you will create the image the user will search (in a 3D environment),
- create your object / image,
- set the camera preview as background (take a look at Vuforia samples),
- Move the object depending on the accelerometer (in order to "fix" the object in the reality).
- Finally depending on the distance play a sound.